# Failing to update database schema using Entity Framework CLI

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, dotnet-cli

I have created an empty `dotnet new webapi` project on my machine using .NET CLI. I have setup `ApplicationDbContext` as well as a connection string in `appsettings.json` and created a model that I would like to create in the database.

The project successfully builds and when run the command

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

it generates the `Migrations` folder with the migration script in it.

The problem arises when running the script and updating the database using the `dotnet ef database update` where it throws the following error:

> Entity Framework Core 6.0.6 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.6' with options: None ...
> ...
> ...
> ClientConnectionId:#@#@#@@-####-####-@###-#@#@#@#@
> Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
> Login failed for user 'abc###\Guest'.

I am not sure why it is throwing this error and how it can be fixed.

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=BookClub;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

`BoockClub.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.6">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.6">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

`ApplicationDbContext.cs`:

```
using BookClub.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BookClub.Data;

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
  public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
  {
  }

  public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

`CategoryController.cs`:

```
using BookClub.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BookClub.Controllers;

public class CategoryController : Controller
{
  private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

  public CategoryController(ApplicationDbContext db)
  {
    _db = db;
  }

  public IActionResult Index()
  {
    var categoryList = _db.Categories.ToList();
    return View();
  }
}
```

System:

- macOS 12.2.1

Applications:

- VS Code
- Docker - SQL Server
- SQL Server extension for VS Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is your connection string.

`Trusted_Connection=True;` implies that your app is authenticating using Windows Credentials, which won't work unless you're running Windows in Docker with all necessary configs.

You need to create a SQL Authenticated DB user (with Username and Password) then change the connection string

**Old Value**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=BookClub;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
```

**New Value**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=BookClub;User Id=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword;"
  }
```

If you're using SQL Server Management Studio, use the following options to create the username and password:

[image]

Comment: @GurpreetSingh There is this website that helps you create the Connection String with additional info https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: That is brilliant. Cheers for that. 